# LitElement and .bind(this)

Tags: bind, lit-element

I'm finding a little confusing sometimes you need to bind the context to a function call and sometimes not. When exactly can you avoid it and when you not?

What's the difference between those lines?

```html
    <a @click="${this.handler.bind(this)}">link</a>

    <a @click="${this.handler()}">link</a>

    <a @click="${this.handler}">link</a>

    <a @click="${()=>this.handler()}">link</a>
```

Also sometimes in the `constructor()` you need

```js
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
```

to make the function call works, sometimes you not. What's the differences between all those cases?

Answer (score 0):

In the first 4 lines I am guessing you usually wrap them in between `${` and `}`.
With this mention these 3 lines:

```
<a @click="${this.handler.bind(this)}">link</a>
<a @click="${this.handler}">link</a>
<a @click="${()=>this.handler()}">link</a>
```

would be pretty similar in the effect. When you attach an event handler you need to pass a reference to a function/method to call, while the second line:

```
<a @click="${this.handler()}">link</a>
```

will most likely just be wrong. That's because you will be calling `this.handler()` as soon as the rendering is done. The only way it might make some sense it would be if the `handler` method returns a function.

Going back to the first 3 lines: they will indeed have very similar effect, as in all of them you are passing references to a local method render, but:

- the first one doesn't need binding as the method will anyway be
  called in `this` context (but I guess it doesn't hurt either)
- the    third one adds the definition of an anonymous function as an
  event    handler, which when called it will invoke `this.handler`

So the second one is basically the simplest and easiest to read.

When it comes to the need to call bind in some of the cases: that's needed when your method is called from another context. Let's say you pass it as a callback parameter to a method running in another class. When you method will be called there, it will have by default the context of that other object. So you will need to use .bind(this) to make sure that when the method is called in your element's context.

Your method does work, but it's running from another `this`. So maybe that's why some of the times you don't notice the need to `.bind(this)`. If the method just shows a message, calls some other external service, or anything else that is not part of your object's definition (that doesn't use `this.something`), it will work without using bind.

**UPDATE**: in fact I think an event handler will always run in the context of the element that originated that event. I am guessing that lit just does that `.bind(this)` when we use that `@click=` syntax, as it would make a lot of sense.

Comment: let me be clear, of course here `this.handler()` is a method of the class that extends `LitElement`, so with `this` I'm expecting to refer to the class and have access to its props and methods

Answer (score 0):

Note that binding directly in templates is generally not a good idea. It can result in performance issues and components re-rendering when they shouldn't.
https://github.com/43081j/eslint-plugin-lit/blob/master/docs/rules/no-template-bind.md

As to why you sometimes need to bind consider this:

```js
@customElement('main-page')
export class MainPage extends LitElement {
  @property()
  public name = "bob";

  render() {
    return html`<button @click=${this.clicked}>Click Me!</button>`;
  }

  clicked() {
      console.log("clicked " + this.name);
      console.log("this in clicked: " + this)
      setTimeout(this.sayHi, 1000);
  }

  sayHi() {
    console.log("this in sayHi: " + this)
    alert(`Hello, ${this.name}!`);
  }
 }
```

If we click on the button, we get the name logged properly:
[image]

But the name isn't shown in the alert:

[image]

If we look at `this` in both functions we get different results:

[image]

One is an HTMLElement and the other one is a Window. What `this` refers to is different once we pass `sayHi` to `setTimeout`.

`Bind` will fix this by making sure that this refers to the right object.

While we could do `setTimeout(this.sayHi.bind(this), 1000);` and it would fix our issue but it's not very clean and it's error prone. We could bind it in the constructor, but this also isn't much better.

The cleanest way to do it is to directly bind `this` by using an arrow function instead:

```
sayHi = () => {
[...]
```

This notation binds `this` to the object itself. We then do not need to bind it explicitly ourselves.
Once we do that, both `this` refer to the right object:

[image]